# How to stop rec call in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I want to represent a number as a list of digits. I did most of the implementations but I do not know how to stop the recursive call after parsing the whole number. I know this solution is not the best but I have no other idea.

Here is my implementation, if someone has some tips & tricks please let me know.

```
trans(NR,Q,L):-
    NR > 0,
    Q is NR mod 10,
    NR1 is NR div 10,
    Q1 is NR1 mod 10,
    trans(NR1,Q1,[Q|L]).
```

for example:

`?- trans(345,5,L).` should return `L=[3,4,5]`

Comment: what about NR =< 0 ? and you can simplify the whole avoiding Q. Compute it locally.

Comment: Yes, not very clear why you need the second argument, or what the predicate is actually trying to do: do you simply want to represent a number as a list of its digits?

Comment: To stop the recursion successfully (currently your recursion does stop, but with failure when `NR` goes to `0`), you need a successful base case, which describes the trivial case and describes the "end state". In your case, you keep dividing down `NR` and it will eventually be 0. So you need a case that tells you what `L` is if you have 0.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response but I was at work and could not access the link. I know my code is not so good but it was my single idea for the moment. I'll try now to modify it